# PHP AJAX data not returned to HTML file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having trouble getting a value returned from a database from a HTML file using AJAX and PHP. I have a mysql database with headCode value and 5 locations. The use enters a headCode and one location. If the headCode and one of the locations mach a record the PHP will return a value. EG headcode - 1A, location, Victoria will return value 17.

I had it all working with out the Ajax but with Ajax i cannot get the value to return.

HTML code

```
<script src="\jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{idheadcode: $('#headcode').val(), idlocation: $('#location').val()},   
            url: "headcode_Db_connect.php",
            success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="input">
    HeadCode: <input type="text" id="headcode">
    End Location:<input type="text" id="location">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $headcode = $_POST['headcode'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="789852"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="work"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "headcodes";

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE headcode= '$headcode'AND (location1= '$location' OR location2 = '$location' OR location3= '$location' OR location4 = '$location' OR location5 = '$location')" ;
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql, $link);

    if($result1){
        //echo "Successful";
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $number = $row['number'];
    }

$myJson = json_encode ($number);
echo $number;
echo "10";

?>
```

The echo 10 at the bottom of the php file is just for testing. This is returned to the HTML file proving the file is passing data

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: in your while loop block you had `$number` as array. You should not echo array . It will be fatal error

Comment: " i cannot get the value to return". This is relatively vague and meaningless. What debugging / tracing have you done? Does the ajax call complete successfully (200 OK response)? Do you get any error messages? What output do you get? Have you traced the flow of your PHP code (either by debugging if you have an appropriate IDE, or simply by var_dump of variables to show what's happening)?

Comment: @krishnakumar I can't see any evidence to support your statement. $number is assigned as one value from the row. Since it's reading a DB field it can't be an array. Depending on how many rows are returned though, there is potentially a logical error in that $number is not defined outside the loop and only the value from the last row, if any, will get returned to the client.

Comment: what is your current output

Comment: Try initializing the number variable before you get into the while loop

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $number = $row['number'];
    }` should be moved inside `if ($result1)` for reliability. Otherwise if the query fails for any reason it will result in an exception when trying to read the result as an array. You also aren't trying to fetch a SQL error and log it, which you probably should. Anyway like I said it all needs rewriting into a new library anyway. And you need to provide specific details of the problem.

Comment: If I change to `echo $number` to echo`$myJson` it returns a null value to the HTML.

Comment: why do you need it as JSON? Your JS code is just sending is directly displaying it on screen (in an element) as text. JSON is not meant to be human-readable, it's a structure for transmitting complex objects. You're sending a single number (so no identifying structure needed) which you then immediately display on screen for users in the same format. JSON is redundant for this purpose. If the code you've got works without the JSON, then leave it like that.

Comment: ADyson thanks for the comments. I have removed the Json and placed the while loop in the `if` function. It works great now so i will start to spend some time learning pdo which will be a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file you are accessing the wrong keys. Access the right keys as follows :

```
 $headcode = $_POST['idheadcode'];
$location = $_POST['idlocation'];
```

Also do not use the deprecated mysql extension. I advise you start learning prepared statements using pdo or mysqli

Another advise, when in the development environment,  always enable error reporting as follows

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);//place at the top of the script
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great. i understand i need to learn pdo or mysqli which I will do soon but I only do this coding for fun to learn not as a job or for any qualifications. Thank you for your help